# NAT ing to port 80 not working,when request comes to itself

Tags: virtualization, iptables, routing, nat, port-forwarding

We have a machine with Virtual Machine with local IP NAT ed to Public IPs.

When a request comes to public IP on port 80 it will be redirected to VM with local IP.

This is the iptable rule we are using:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d public-ip --dport 80 -j DNAT --to ip-of-vm:80
```

There are cases that request has to be send from vm to itself, through public IP.

But it's not happening ie VM can not communicate to itself through public IP.
I tried to telnet to public IP port 80 from the vm ,but connection is not happening even with network connectivity.

Is there a way I can solve this issue?

`netstat` on vm shows

```
$ netstat -ntp |grep 80
tcp        0      1 localip:53067    public-ip:80        SYN_SENT    22226/telnet**
```

output of `iptables-save -c`:

**consider 
192.168.61.31 as pub ip on eth0
192.168.61.40 as pub ip on eth0:1**

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Wed Jun 13 13:29:06 2012
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [9:1584]
:INPUT ACCEPT [9:1584]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [12:720]
[222:13320] -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.61.40/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.43:80
[164:9840] -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.61.31/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.42:80
[15:16631] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
[76:5092] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/32 -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.61.31
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun 13 13:29:06 2012

# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Wed Jun 13 13:29:06 2012
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [491283:64985216]
:INPUT ACCEPT [467366:60033592]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [23752:4941940]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [472767:103297872]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [496519:108239812]
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun 13 13:29:06 2012

# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Wed Jun 13 13:29:06 2012
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [467244:60021819]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [23744:4941444]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [472681:103288146]
[0:0] -A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun 13 13:29:06 2012
```

Comment: Why does it need to connect to itself using a public IP address?

Comment: Our project Architecture is like that.It checks whether data exist in that machine through Public ip.
Can you tell me why this is happening...when vm communicates to public ip it will be send back to vm through NAT,but why it is not giving any response. netstat reveals public-ip:80 SYN_SENT on the vm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing another rule:

`iptables -A POSTROUTING -s $PRIVATE_NET -o $PRIVATE_INTERFACE -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source $PUBLIC_IP`

Comment: That didnt help...
i am having a similar problem explained here 
http://serverfault.com/questions/74182/service-cant-connect-to-self-using-public-ip-nat-problem?rq=1
but it looks complex for me,can u help in solving this issue.

Comment: 1) please post the output of `iptables-save -c`.
2) note on the rules http://easyfwgen.morizot.net/ would generate given your requirements. It's not quite good for production use, but seeing which rules go where is handy.

Comment: done..can u please go through it..

Comment: you didn't add the entry I suggested, did you?

Comment: I added that in VM with local ip...
in our Host public ip is aliased as eth0,eth0:1
each Public ip is NAted to local ip of VMs.

Comment: in our case each public Ip is NATed to each VM.so we can not NAT local network to single public ip.Can u help..

Comment: You need to add that at the NAT/router box.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3755/discussion-between-user113505-and-nekojirusou)